# Testing an implementation of an LSTM in Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm

I'm trying to use the Pytorch implementation of an LSTM [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50168224/does-a-clean-and-extendable-lstm-implementation-exists-in-pytorch). I'm including it here for reference. It consists of two classes, LSTMCell and LSTM, where LSTMCell is just a single unit and LSTM puts stacks multiple units together to create a full LSTM model

```
import math
import torch as th
import torch.nn as nn

class LSTMCell(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, bias=True):
        super(LSTM, self).__init__()
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.bias = bias
        self.i2h = nn.Linear(input_size, 4 * hidden_size, bias=bias)
        self.h2h = nn.Linear(hidden_size, 4 * hidden_size, bias=bias)
        self.reset_parameters()

    def reset_parameters(self):
        std = 1.0 / math.sqrt(self.hidden_size)
        for w in self.parameters():
            w.data.uniform_(-std, std)

    def forward(self, x, hidden):
        if hidden is None:
            hidden = self._init_hidden(x)

        h, c = hidden
        h = h.view(h.size(1), -1)
        c = c.view(c.size(1), -1)
        x = x.view(x.size(1), -1)

        # Linear mappings
        preact = self.i2h(x) + self.h2h(h)

        # activations
        gates = preact[:, :3 * self.hidden_size].sigmoid()
        g_t = preact[:, 3 * self.hidden_size:].tanh()
        i_t = gates[:, :self.hidden_size]
        f_t = gates[:, self.hidden_size:2 * self.hidden_size]
        o_t = gates[:, -self.hidden_size:]

        c_t = th.mul(c, f_t) + th.mul(i_t, g_t)

        h_t = th.mul(o_t, c_t.tanh())

        h_t = h_t.view(1, h_t.size(0), -1)
        c_t = c_t.view(1, c_t.size(0), -1)
        return h_t, (h_t, c_t)

    @staticmethod
    def _init_hidden(input_):
        h = th.zeros_like(input_.view(1, input_.size(1), -1))
        c = th.zeros_like(input_.view(1, input_.size(1), -1))
        return h, c
```

```
class LSTM(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, bias=True):
        super().__init__()
        self.lstm_cell = LSTMCell(input_size, hidden_size, bias)

    def forward(self, input_, hidden=None):
        # input_ is of dimensionalty (1, time, input_size, ...)

        outputs = []
        for x in torch.unbind(input_, dim=1):
            hidden = self.lstm_cell(x, hidden)
            outputs.append(hidden[0].clone())

        return torch.stack(outputs, dim=1)
```

I'm doing the following simple test:

```
x = torch.randn(1, 3, 2, 4)
model = LSTM(4, 5, False)
model(x)
```

and I get the following error. What exactly is the problem here?

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-09e5544a61fc> in <module>
----> 1 model = LSTM(4, 5, False)

<ipython-input-30-9ad06cd4b768> in __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, bias)
      3     def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, bias=True):
      4         super().__init__()
----> 5         self.lstm_cell = LSTMCell(input_size, hidden_size, bias)
      6 
      7     def forward(self, input_, hidden=None):

<ipython-input-29-c91ddfb9dfae> in __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, bias)
      6 
      7     def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, bias=True):
----> 8         super(LSTM, self).__init__()
      9         self.input_size = input_size
     10         self.hidden_size = hidden_size

TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to `super()` should be class itself, not a different class.

```py
class LSTMCell(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, bias=True):
        super(LSTM, self).__init__()
#             ^^^^ self is not an instance of LSTM but LSTMCell
```

It should be:

```py
super(LSTMCell, self).__init__()
```

Since Python 3 you can omit the arguments to super to get the same result (as you have done in the `LSTM` class):

```py
super().__init__()
```

Comment: that fixed it thank you. But now there seems to be an issue with the input. I tried both x = [1,3,2,4] and x = [1,3,4,2] and neither worked. There seems to be a dimension problem with matrix multiplication. In particular, it seems like the resulting matrix for i2h and h2h is 5x20, which suggests to me that the "input" and "hidden" layers are switched. Separate post?

Comment: Yes, that's a separate issue, but the input to the `LSTM` must have size *[batch_size, seq_len, input_size]* (only 3 dimensions) and the input to `LSTMCell` would usually be `[batch_size, input_size]* (2 dimensions) but because of `x = x.view(x.size(1), -1)` it must be *[1, batch_size, input_size]*, so `self.lstm_cell(x.unsqueeze(0), hidden)` should do the trick.