# Why is Pytorch built-in LSTM much faster than custom written ones?

Tags: pytorch

I have tried several custom LSTM cells, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50168224/does-a-clean-and-extendable-lstm-implementation-exists-in-pytorch#:%7E:text=The%20best%20implementation%20I%20found%20is%20here%20https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fpytorch%2Fbenchmark%2Fblob%2Fmaster%2Frnns%2Fbenchmarks%2Flstm_variants%2Flstm.py,you%20take%20the%20dropout%20parts%20away%20you%20get) but they're all very slow compared to the built-in torch.nn.LSTM. Why is this the case? How can I write an optimum built-in LSTM?